# MySQL nested queries

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project using a MySQL database and we'd like to combine a query which was previously made in several steps into one step.
The queries are created in a Java-App using Hibernate.

**Goal**
The goal of the query (or queries up to now) is the following: Loading a subset of data from several different tables (according to some filters and sorted).

**Database Structure**
The structure of the database can not be changed. I'll show here the needed tables with some example entries.

```
Table t1

id         class    counts      ... other parameters
-------    -----    ------
1          B5.2     124831
2          A7.9     83482
3          M5.5     53124812


Table t2

event_id    reconstruction_algorithm       ... other parameters
--------    ------------------------
1           0
1           0
1           0
1           1
1           1
1           1
1           2
1           2
1           2
1           3
2           0
2           0
2           0
2           0
2           1
2           1
2           1
2           2
2           2
2           2
2           3
2           3
...         ...
```

**Desired Result**
I'm trying to find a query which can (in one step) do the following:

- Get selected entries of table t1 (e.g. id and class) for some rows which meet some filter criteria (e.g. counts between 100000 and 150000)
- Get the maximum amount of entries withe the same reconstruction_algorithm which belong to a single entry in t1 (e.g for the entry with id 1 this would be 3)

**The problem**

Up to now we used two requests. The first was used to get the entries of t1 which meet the filter criteria:

```
SELECT class, counts FROM t1 WHERE parameterX <= 123 AND parameterY >= 20;
```

The second was used to get the according amount of entries from t2:

```
SELECT MAX(tm.tNum) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as tNum from t2 t, t1 q WHERE q.id = t.event_id GROUP BY t.reconstruction_algorithm) tm;
```

Now I'd like to combine those two queries into one query. I tried doing this the following way:

```
SELECT q.id, q.class, MAX(tm.tmNum) AS nmbr
FROM t1 q, (SELECT COUNT(*) as tmNum from t2 t, t1 q WHERE
                q.id = t.event_id GROUP BY t.reconstruction_algorithm) tm
WHERE q.parameterX >= 123 ORDER BY q.counts DESC;
```

The problem is now, that this query (tried in different ways) does return only a single row, although the outer query returns several rows. So I'd like the inner query to be run for every result of the outer query.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I hope somebody knows the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query does what you are asking. The sub select gets the counts for each id. I then joined it back to t1. The outer query gets the max for each id. I didn't put the WHERE clause since I don't know the criteria but you can easily add it.

Here's a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d24d2/1)

```
select id, 
  class, 
  counts, 
  max(numOcc) as Occ
from t1
left join 
(SELECT event_id, reconstruction_algorithm, count(1) as numOcc from t2 
  group by event_id, reconstruction_algorithm) a
on t1.id = a.event_id
group by t1.id, t1.class, t1.counts
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the inner query with the outer (the inner reference to the same table should be removed):

```
SELECT q.id, q.class, MAX(tm.tmNum) AS nmbr
FROM t1 q, (SELECT COUNT(*) as tmNum 
            from t2 t
            WHERE q.id = t.event_id 
            GROUP BY t.reconstruction_algorithm) tm
WHERE q.parameterX >= 123 
  AND parameterY >= 20
ORDER BY q.counts DESC;
```

Updated suggestion:

```
SELECT q.id, q.class, MAX(tm.tmNum) AS nmbr 
FROM t1 q, (SELECT t2.event_id, COUNT(*) as tmNum             
            from t2              
            GROUP BY t2.event_id, t2.reconstruction_algorithm) tm 
WHERE tm.event_id = q.id 
group by q.id, q.class 
ORDER BY q.counts DESC
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I got an error saying `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'q.id' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: Ah, I did not look that close on your query. The subselect should not be a derived table. I'll update the suggestion